# How to get multiple data from List using Spinner?

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I want more required data from my Spinner but unable to get. This is my list `["id":"1","title":"test 1","tableid":"my_value"]` and my Spinner showing dropdown of `table` to users and I want `my_value` from list. But I want to show users to `table`. How can I achieve this?

**`table` is properly showing on `dropdown` but item is not `selecting` and unable to get  `my_value` data.**

Like this:
[image]

This is my Model Class

```
public class myModel {
    String id;
    String title;
    String tableid;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getTableId() {
        return tableid;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getTitle();
    }
}
```

This is spinner XML

```
<Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

This is Spinner Code

```
ArrayList<myModel> dropList = new ArrayList<>();
//DropList data is like this = ["id":"1","title":"test 1","tableid":"my_value"]
            ArrayAdapter<myModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.my_spinner_textview, dropList); // my_spinner_textview is same as simple_spinner_item_view
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int position, long id) {
                   
                    myModel modelcls = dropList.get(position);
                    String val= modelcls.getTableId();
                    String val2= modelcls.getTitle();
                    Toast.makeText(ShayariEditor.this, "value1: "+val, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(ShayariEditor.this, "value2: "+val2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: Try looking at [How to get the Selected item position and Value in spinner-Android?](https://www.ingenioustechies.com/android-how-to-get-the-selected-item-position-and-value-in-spinner/).

Comment: @AliasCartellano Thank you. But I want complete Model Data from single id. I just updated my question for better understanding.

Comment: try this : https://www.journaldev.com/9231/android-spinner-drop-down-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Just create a custom Array with different data and can easily access them using `position` of onItemSelected.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int position, long id) {
```

It works very fine. You'll achieve 2 data with the same spinner.